# "something come something", or foo-come-bar

Tags: hyphenation, archaicisms

Is the bold construct below valid? Does it have a name? What sort of punctuation would you use for it?

> Fnord, the **something-come-such-and-so**, was under development for a year or so. It suffered a redesign late last year to satisfy changing customer demands. We had a something on hand; customers wanted such-and-so.

I swear I've heard or read this construction before. It falls on my ear as old fashioned (dare I say "vintage"?), though not quite archaic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of *[cum](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cum?q=-cum-)* (/kʌm/), which means:

> combined with; *also* used as (used to describe things with a dual
>   nature or function): a study-*cum*-bedroom

It's also legal to use it without hyphenation:

> The same applies to his long-running Korean-war vet cum knight errant.

Comment: Though given its more vulgar definition nowadays, using it is likely to get you some odd looks.

Comment: @JohnClifford Yeah, that's why I'd tend to go the whole nine yards, and both hyphenate **and** italicize _cum_ were I to use it.

Comment: @JohnClifford It is nothing other than the Latin for *with*. Many villages in England include it in their name, usually where two parishes have at some point in history been combined e.g. *Chorlton-cum-Hardy*, *Horton-cum-Studley* etc.

Comment: @WS2 I'm aware of that, but it's also now a horribly-mangled spelling of "come" as a euphemism for semen. :P

Comment: It's actually legal to use it however you want as long as you have consent to do so and avoid any *minor* errors...

Comment: @JohnClifford Ignorance is regrettably in the ascendant, and has been for a few decades.

Comment: @WS2 and I weep every day for that being the case.